# Ноутбук не видит телефон в режиме разработчика android

Tags: android, ноутбук

Собственно в чем проблема понятия не имею, подключаю другие телефоны все нормально видит, подключают мой телефон к другим ноутбукам \ стационарам так же все нормально видит. Телефон включен в режиме разработчика, ноутбук остальные трубы так же видит, что может быть? Перестанавливал драйвер в диспетчере задач вручную как это написано в интернете, но мой телефон так же не видно... Что предложите, господа знатоки?

Comment: Кстати стационар дома видит его.

Comment: Sorry за оффтоп, но что вы написали в метках? Я честно зашел сюда только, чтобы посмотреть на метку "разработчика". Вероятно, это был "режим разработчика"?

Comment: собственно да... оно разделило просто

Comment: Если система Windows 7, то ответ очевиден...так какая система у вас?

Comment: семерка, а в чем ответ очевиден? На стационарном все нормально.

Comment: Для семерки необходим специальный USB драйвер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подключаем телефон к компьютеру. Для виндузятников. Запускаем cmd.exe и пишем три комманды.

```
cd \android-sdk\platform-tools (Папка где установлен Android SDK)
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Срабатывает в 95% случаев. Версия для красноглазиков(если запускать как отдельный bash скрипт не будет работать, нужно вводить строго по очереди):

```
cd /android-sdk/platform-tools (Папка где установлен Android SDK)
sudo su
./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
```

Comment: не помогло

Comment: Еще можно попробовать 1) Переткнуть в соседний USB порт 2) с сайта производителей скачать SDK/драйвер/патч 3)Скрипт сверху запустить без подключенного телефона и только потом включить. Если и это все не помогает, то нужно гораздо больше информации о системе чем вы написали.

Comment: Тогда это контроллер USB на материнской плате ноутбука, USB принтер/сканер/флэшку попробуйте подключить к ноутбуку, они будут печатать/сканировать/передавать данные?

Comment: Дело набирает интересный оборот, а что за модель телефона?

Comment: http://www.samsung.com/ru/support/detail/supportPrdDetail.do?menu=SP01&prd_mdl_cd=GT-S5830OKASER&srchword=GT-S5830

Вот Samsung Kies 2.0 скачайте может это поможет

Comment: Смешно как-то но после установки Kies у меня перестал запускаться еклипс...